# why anchor for sliding-in div does not work when text inside the div

Tags: jquery, css, transition

I have an anchor and when click on it, a div with class`box` is sliding in.
This works perfect without text inside the div.
but when i put some text inside the div, the anchor does not work anymore. 
Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

html:

```
<a class="slide" href="#">Slide Out</a>

<div id="fade-in" class="box"></div>
```

Css:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #009de1;
  cursor: pointer; 
  float: right;
  color: #fff;

}

.box {
   display: block;
    background: #009de1;  
    float: right;
    color: #fff;
 }

 #fade-in {
    height: 20px;
    width: 1px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .75s ease;  
 }

 #fade-in.show {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 20px;
    width: 200px;

 }
```

the js:

```
$('.slide').on('click', function(){
   $('#fade-in').toggleClass('show');
});
```

Here is the fiddle without text. You can see the anchor works
https://jsfiddle.net/94uhxjgk/41/

And here i have put some text inside the div and the anchor is not working anymore
https://jsfiddle.net/94uhxjgk/43/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/talut/afy3sftL/15/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because since your text is to large it is getting over your click area so it never triggers the click event, to fix this you can add

```
#fade-in{
....
overflow:hidden;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/ks82n3tu/1/)

**Edit**

Since the content of your element is bigger than the width..[image]

The content is render over your Slide Out element, you can't see it because it has opacity set to 0.. so you will actually click the text, and not the Slide Out element..
Overflow hidden.. actually clips the overflow text in that way you are able to click the Slide Out.

Comment: this solve his problem.. but can you explain it more, how overflow:hidden work,

Comment: i agree! Works perfect now.